Using [Authorize] attribute in non-controller based class in ASP.NET Core Web API project
I have a need to decorate non-controller based class / method with [Authorize] attribute or custom implementation of IAuthorizationFilter. The non-controller based methods will always responsible for performing the required tasks for the particular controller action, and it is possible to involve more than one method involve for particular controller action.
For instance in the example below the controller action GetData() won't perform any authorization but will simply call lib.Method1() and lib.Method2() to get the data. And each of the lib methods will look for required scopes in the token before giving the results back. If user does not have permission for Method1, but only got permission for Method2, it is possible the GetData() returns partial data.
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<DataModel> GetData()
{
    var x = lib.Method1();
    var y = lib.Method2();
    return OkObjectResult(new DataModel(x, y));
}

public class CustomLib
{
    [MyAuthZ("Method1.Read")]
    public string Method1()
    {
        return "m1";
    }

    [MyAuthZ("Method2.Read")]
    public string Method2()
    {
        return "m2";
    }
}

My first question is if this is something doable? I tried custom IAuthorizationFilter but didn't find a way to have it activate it in non-controller based class.
If this is something doable appreciate some pointers that I could give a try.
I have the following implementation for the custom AuthZ, but finding it hard how to make it automatically invoked in the non-controller based class/method.
public class  MyAuthZAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute<MyAuthZFilter>
{
    public MyAuthZAttribute(params string[] scopes)
    {
        base.Arguments = new object[] { scopes };
    }
}

public class MyAuthZFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string[] scopes;

    public MyAuthZFilter(string[] scopes)
    {
        this.scopes = scopes;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (user.Identities == null || !user.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            return;
        }

        if (scopes != null && scopes.Length > 0)
        {
            bool hasScope = scopes.Any(scope => user.HasClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope", scope));

            if (!hasScope)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


you have to use the custom code to implement your requirement as you can only use the IAuthorizationFilter at the controller action level. For that first you have to create custom middleware which can check authorization and invoke that before the actual method logic is executed. create rapper method which will handle the authorization checks before calling the target methods.
